# clone dom for different amount of number-inputs to generate a summary

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a simple table with the following specs:

[image]

This pretty simple overview is used to manually input any amount for a certain row. In that example you see `1` in "Bestellmenge" (quantity).

To give the user a final summary, I'd like to generate a small box with the inputs he has given (to confirm everything is how it should  be).

For that case, I prepared a small skeletton like this:

```
<div class="alert alert-warning">
    <strong>Please verify:</strong><br><br>
    You are going to order:
    <span class="preview_amount"></span>
    <span class="preview_article_name"></span>
    <span>for each</span>
    <span class="preview_price_unit">11</span>€
    <br>
    <hr>

    The final price will be <span class="preview_final_price"></span>€
</div>
```

The Problem I'm encountering is, how to "duplicate" the values. Is this even a good approach? The amount of inputs-field vary and aren't always 5 (otherwise I'd use this as a fix amount with fix id's).

I had a similar use-case before, but there were only 1 set of values. I was hiding the `preview-text`
, filling in the values after `keyUp` and when every input was filled with a value, I simply faded the text in.

So, to give an example:

> Lets pretend I'm trying to order `1, 0, 3, 0, 2`

My output has to have 3x the "skeletton" - for each article once. I havdn't had problems to just adjust 1 value from 1 field. Is the suggested way to iterate through these inputs with a for-each (~) and "re-create / dupe / clone" the skeletton?